# Let $f: \mathbb R^k \rightarrow \mathbb R$ continuous and unbounded in both directions. Show $f(\mathbb R^k)=\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb R^k \rightarrow \mathbb R$ continuous and unbounded in both directions. Show $f(\mathbb R^k)=\mathbb R$

I must show that any $x \in \mathbb R$ also lies in $f(\mathbb R^k)$.

Idea:

Let $x \in \mathbb R^k$ and $y=f(x)$. Then since $f$ is continuous I can choose $\epsilon>0$ and $\delta >0$. The ball $B_\delta(x)$ in $\mathbb R^k$ is nonempty and all points must be within $\pm \epsilon$ of $f(x)$.

Comment: Why to use $\;A\;$ for $\;\Bbb R^k\;$ ? ...odd.

Comment: Your question is incorrect. Since if $f$ is onto replace it by $|f|$. It is still unbounded and continuous but it is not onto.

Comment: This, as posed, is false: $\;f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R\;(k=1)\;$ defined by $\;f(x):=x^2\;$ fulfills the conditions yet it is not surjective.

Comment: both previous mentioned situations are **bounded bellow** so they don't count :P

Comment: Well @janmarqz :they counted **before** the original question was edited and changed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $c\in \mathbb R$, there exists some vectors $x,y\in \mathbb R^k$ so that $c\in [f(y), f(x)]$. This is because $f$ is unbounded from both sides and the interval $[f(x), f(y)]$ can be set as large as we want.

Now, take a look at the function $g(t) = f(tx + (1-t) y)$ which is a function from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$ and continuous. Since $g(0)=f(y)\leq c$ and $g(1)=f(x)\geq c$, by the intermediate value theorem, there exists some $t$ for which $g(t) = c$. This $t$ gives a vector $z=tx+(1-t)y$ for which $f(z)=c$.

Comment: Unbounded in both directions.

Comment: No, this function is bounded bellow @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla

Comment: This function is bounded bellow, the hypothesis is unbounded in both directions.

Comment: People should begin to pay attention when a question has been edited: this answer is from two hours ago, when the original question, which did **not** mention "bounded in both directions" was posted. Thus, the answer is a right counter example *to the original question* . This is one reason more why there should be a limit for questions to be changed...

Comment: Yes, well, I do try to pay attention when questions change, however, believe it or not, there are moments in my life when I am away from my computer for a few hours. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks how do you show continuity of the g(t) ?

Comment: With ease. Look at some properties of continuous functions you mentioned in classes.

Answer (score 4):

The image of a connected space by a continuous function is connected, so $f(\mathbb R^k)$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$ connected and unbounded in both directions...

Comment: Is there someway of proving this without using the connectedness, because I've never been introduced to this concept ?

Answer (score 3):

Since $f$ is unbounded in both directions, for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we have some $y_1,y_2\in\mathbb{R}^k$ such that $f(y_1) < x < f(y_2)$. Thus using the [intermediate value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) there must exist some $y\in\mathbb{R}^k$ such that $f(y)=x$.

---

Note that we use the [generalized intermediate value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem#Generalization) along with with the following facts:

1. $\mathbb{R}^k$ is connected.
2. $\mathbb{R}$ is a totally ordered set, with the usual order topology.
3. $f$ is continuous.

---

One can also use the standard intermediate value theorem:

Let $y_1$ , $y_2$ and $x$ be as described above. Let $l_{y_1,y_2}$ be the (inclusive) k-dimensional line-segment between $y_1$ and $y_2$. We can rotate and move $\mathbb{R}^k$, via a rigid motion linear map $\tau$, so that $l_{y_1,y_2}$ lays on one of the axes. We shall use $X$ to denote that particular axis. Note that we have $\tau(l_{y_1,y_2})\subset X$ and in particular, we can write:
$$
\tau(y_1)=(0,...,a_1,...,0) \\
\tau(y_2)=(0,...,a_2,...,0)
$$
for some $a_1,a_2\in\mathbb{R}$. Without lose of generality we shall assume $a_1 <a_2$.

Finally, we define the map:
$$
g: [a_1,a_2] \to X \\
y \mapsto (0,...,y,...,0)
$$
Composing our functions we get: $$\,(f \circ \tau^{-1} \circ g) \,:\, [a_1,a_2] \to \mathbb{R}$$ If we observe the continuity of $f \circ \tau^{-1}$, while limiting our domain to $X$ we get the ordinary definition of continuity of single variable functions, and hence $f \circ \tau^{-1} \circ g$ is also continuous. Thus we can use the regular intermediate value theorem, along with the fact that:
$$
(f \circ \tau^{-1} \circ g)(a_1) = f(y_1) < x < f(y_2) = (f \circ \tau^{-1} \circ g)(a_2)
$$
to show that there exists some $y\in [a_1,a_2]$ such that  $(f \circ \tau^{-1} \circ g)(y) =f(\,(\tau^{-1} \circ g)(y)\,)= x$.

Comment: But to use this theorem we must have $f: [a;b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ ? But here $f$ is not defined on an interval?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen You can use the [generalization of this theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem#Generalization).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot use a theorem I've not yet studied :(

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen I've edited my answer. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your inspiring answer.

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen Thanks, although I feel slightly embarrassed after seeing 5xum's new answer which essentially the same as mine, but much simpler. Both  answers limit $f$ to the line between $y_1$ and $y_2$, which turns the function into a single-variable function.